# Writing astronomical units in the labels of plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I use `matplotlib` to plot my data but I need to write in labels the `unit` and I it doesn't work the way it works in latex. For instance in latex by using `siunitx` package then I can write `\arcsecond` unit but how should it be done in `matplotlib`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
import pylab as plt 
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter
x = range(10)
plt.plot(x)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%d unit'))
```

Comment: Add the label to the X axis. If that was your question. If not, then you need to clarify your question more.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I supposed the imports are already done, but its better like so.

Comment: I could not make it to work for `\arcsecond` unit. Do you know how it should be done?

Comment: Since the unicode for arcsecond is `U+2033`, you can try: `u'\u2033'`